# Reverse a sub list

Tags: python, reverse, singly-linked-list

I have to reverse a sub list in my linked list and then return the original linked list but with the sublist reversed. The question is as follows...

Given the head of a LinkedList and two positions ‘p’ and ‘q’, reverse the LinkedList from position ‘p’ to ‘q’.

For example

```
1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> null, p = 2, q = 4 then,
1 -> 4 -> 3 -> 2 -> 5 -> null
```

```
from __future__ import print_function


class Node:
  def __init__(self, value, next=None):
    self.value = value
    self.next = next

  def print_list(self):
    temp = self
    while temp is not None:
      print(temp.value, end=" ")
      temp = temp.next
    print()


def reverse_sub_list(head, p, q):
  start, end = head, head
  previous = None

  while p > 1:
    previous = start
    start = start.next
    p -= 1
  
  while q > 0:
    end = end.next
    q -= 1

  last_node_of_sub_list = start
  sub_list = reverse(start, end)
  previous.next = sub_list
  last_node_of_sub_list.next = end
  return head

  '''
  first_list = head
  last_list = end

  while first_list is not None:
    first_list = first_list.next
  first_list = sub_list

  while sub_list is not None:
    sub_list = sub_list.next
  sub_list = last_list

  return head
  '''

def reverse(head, last_node):
  previous = None

  while head is not last_node:
    _next = head.next
    head.next = previous
    previous = head
    head = _next
  
  return previous


def main():
  head = Node(1)
  head.next = Node(2)
  head.next.next = Node(3)
  head.next.next.next = Node(4)
  head.next.next.next.next = Node(5)

  print("Nodes of original LinkedList are: ", end='')
  head.print_list()
  result = reverse_sub_list(head, 2, 4)
  print("Nodes of reversed LinkedList are: ", end='')
  result.print_list()


main()
```

In my while loops I thought I was connecting the last node of the `first_list` to `sub_list` and the last node of `sub_list` to the `last_list`.

Turns out that when I return head, head is now only `1 -> 2 -> null`
This happens when I reverse the `sub_list` which is fine and I understand that part, but I thought I was reconnecting my lists again.

Comment: Save the node right before `start` (`pre_start`). Then `pre_start.next = sub_list`. Not sure what those last two whiles and assignments were supposed to accomplish.

Comment: Okay, I get it that I can do that and added that part in. I also added the part to connect to the last part of the list as well being that the list is being broken apart in three parts. I still don't know why my while loops didn't work. I thought it was essentially the same thing. Finding the last node in the first list and pointing it to the beginning of the sub list and finding the last node of the sub list and pointing it to the last list which I now see doesn't work because it is going the other way. However, I don't see why the first list and sub list do not attach

Comment: Actually, never mind. I understand it now. my first list last node is the same as the first node of my sub list. By doing first_list.next from the first node of the first list it gives me concatenation of the first list and sub list correctly.

Answer (score 0):

```py
def reverse_sub_list(head, p, q):
  start, end = head, head
  previous = None

  while p > 1:
    previous = start
    start = start.next
    p -= 1
```

Now before moving with `q > 0` while loop, you can just store the values of the previous and current and continue with `q > 0` while loop.
And inside this loop, the reverse is done and q is decremented

```py
connection = previous
tail = current
while q > 0:
     currentNext = current.next
     current.next = previous
     previous = current
     current = currentNext
     q--
```

Now all we have got is whether connection was null or not. If the connection is null, then you can set previous to head else set previous to connection.next

```py
if connection != None:
   connection.next = previous
else:
   head = previous
tail.next = current
return head
```

Full Code :

```py
def reverse_sub_list(head, p, q):
  current = head
  previous = None

  while p > 1:
    previous = start
    current = current.next
    p -= 1

  connection = previous
  tail = current
  while q > 0:
     currentNext = current.next
     current.next = previous
     previous = current
     current = currentNext
     q--
  
  if connection != None:
    connection.next = previous
  else:
    head = previous
  tail.next = current
  return head
```

You can check this link for more explanation and figure : [Click here](https://leetcode.com/problems/reverse-linked-list-ii/discuss/30709/Talk-is-cheap-show-me-the-code-(and-DRAWING))

Answer (score 0):

https://leetcode.com/problems/reverse-linked-list-ii/description/

```
# Definition for singly-linked list.
# class ListNode:
#     def __init__(self, val=0, next=None):
#         self.val = val
#         self.next = next
class Solution:
    def reverseBetween(self, head: ListNode, left: int, right: int) -> ListNode:
        if left == right:
            return head
        prev = start = prev_start = None
        node = head

        for count in range(1, right + 1):
            if count >= left:
                if not start:
                    prev_start = prev
                    start = node
                nxt = node.next
                node.next = prev
                prev = node
                node = nxt
            else:
                prev = node
                node = node.next

        if prev_start:
            prev_start.next = prev
        if start:
            start.next = node

        return head if left > 1 else prev
```